# How to quickly show the solution of a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation
$$x'=x+x^2+tx^3$$
$$x(2)=0$$

and I want to **quickly** (since this is just a small part of much more complex task) show/find the solution (which is $x(t)=0$). Any ideas?

Comment: what about using uniqueness of solutions?

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that I am looking for the GENERAL solution for this ODE.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$x(t):\equiv0\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\tag{1}$$ is a solution of the given ODE and satisfies the initial condition $x(2)=0$. Since the right side
$$f(t,x)=x+x^2+tx^3$$ of the differential equation is continuously differentiable on the whole $(t,x)$-plane it follows from the general existence and uniqueness theorem that $(1)$ is the unique "maximal solution" of the stated IVP.